# AWS EMR Zeppelin is missing MYSQL interpreter

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I launched a fresh AWS EMR Spark cluster with Zeppelin on AWS to query an MYSQL database. When I tried to add an MYSQL interpreter in Zeppelin the option does not exist. I googled to find a way to get the interpreter to display but I didn't find a solution. How can I get the MYSQL interpreter in Zeppelin so I can query the MYSQL database?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark SQL supports many features of `SQL:2003` and `SQL:2011` <sup>[ 1]</sup><sup>[2]</sup>, you may consider doing that that via Spark on Zeppelin by adding dependency.

1. Get a mysql connector with proper version
2. Add it as a dependency to the Spark interpreter on Zeppelin. (I put the jar on the master machine)
   [image]
3. You should be able to access a MySQL table right now. The following is an example using the API of Scala:

   ```
   /* Database Configuration*/
   val jdbcURL = s"jdbc:mysql://${HOST}/${DATABASE}"
   val jdbcUsername = s"${USERNAME}"
   val jdbcPassword = s"${PASSWORD}"

   import java.util.Properties
   val connectionProperties = new Properties()
   connectionProperties.put("user", jdbcUsername)
   connectionProperties.put("password", jdbcPassword)
   connectionProperties.put("driver", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")

   /* Read Data from MySQL */
   val desiredData = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcURL, "${TABLE NAME}", connectionProperties)
   desiredData.printSchema

   /* Data Manipulation */
   desiredData.createOrReplaceTempView("desiredData")
   val query = s"""
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Record Number`
   FROM desiredData
   """
   spark.sql(query).show

   val query2 = s"""
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column1, column2) AS column3
   FROM desiredData
   """
   spark.sql(query2).show
   .
   .
   .
   ```

### Testing Notes:

1. EMR: emr-5.10.0 with Pig 0.17.0, Zeppelin 0.7.3, and ,Spark 2.2.0
2. MySQL: MariaDB 5.2.10

### References

1. Apache Hive (n.d.). *Home*. [online] Cwiki.apache.org. Available at: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Home [Accessed 1 Dec. 2017].
2. Apache Spark (n.d.). *Compatibility with Apache Hive*. [online] spark.apache.org. Available at: ​https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#compatibility-with-apache-hive [Accessed 1 Dec. 2017].